# How to use flask for rendering html files?

Tags: python, html, flask, routes

I'm coding a website with flask. I'm using flask route only to render html files with the function `send_from_directory`. The current structure is the followng:

```
- website
   - app.py
   - views.py
   - static/
       - index.html
       - login.html
       - styles/style.css
       - script/
           - core.js
```

I cant load the css and js with hyperef from a HTML file by using a route AND a hyperlink. For exemple : i can either load the full login page (content and layout) by clicking the link i put in my index page OR i can load the full page by directly typing in the URL, depending on how i code my page. Is there a way to be able to load the full page no matter how i access it?

this is how i code it to access it by typing the url :`<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles/style.css">`

and this is how i code it to access it throught an hyperlink :`<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">`

Thanks for you time.

I tried this:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, send_from_directory


views = Blueprint("views", __name__, static_folder="static", template_folder="static")

@views.route("/")
def home():
    return send_from_directory("static", "index.html")


@views.route("/login")
def login():
    return send_from_directory("static", "login.html")
```

Comment: Is there any reason you cant use `render_template()` function?

Comment: I tried but I have the same problem. Moreover I don't template any contents

Answer (score 0):

It seems you a pretty new to Flask so i will explain it to you but you should go and read the [Flask Documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/).

First the file structure yo have is almost right, you missed the templates folder that Flask uses to identiffy the html/jinja templates.

The way i use to organize my apps:

```
- project-name/
  - app/
    - static/
      - css/
        - style.css
      - js/
        - my_script.js
    - templates/
      - login.html
      - index.html
    - __init__.py #Here the create_app factory
    - views.py
  - run.py #here i instantied the app: app = create_app()
  - .env # Here sets FLASK_APP env variable to FLASK_APP = "run.py" so flask can detect it
```

Now that you have a proper templates folder you can use flask `render_template()` function and `url_for()` inside your templates, so for example if you need to load css or javasriot into your `index.html` file you could doit like so:

*index.html*

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/my_script.js') }}"></script>
</head>
```

Lastly instead of user `send_from_directory` funtcion you will be returning:

```py
@views.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
```